# size(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer,withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) does not work

Tags: ios, swift, childviewcontroller, viewwilltransitiontosize

Apple says:

> "Container view controllers use this method to return the sizes for
> their child view controllers. UIKit calls the method as part of the
> default implementation of the viewWillTransition(to:with:) method for
> view controllers"

And when i first time launch program:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
                       
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let child = ViewControllerChild()
    self.addChildViewController(child)
    self.view.addSubview(child.view)
                    
   
    child.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    child.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]       
}

override func size(forChildContentContainer container: UIContentContainer, withParentContainerSize parentSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
}
```

}
I get full parent vc view's size child view controller's view not (100, 100). So what the real point to override it, if i can respond to trait changes by redefining child vc view's frame in (1st load in viewdidload) then in preferredContentSizeDidChange function?

[image]

Comment: please if you think i made a mistake in my thinking, let me know please!

Comment: or else read question carefully

Answer (score 0):

From the notes you put in the question :

> UIKit calls the method as part of the default implementation of the viewWillTransition(to:with:) method for view controllers

**Question**: Are you sure that overridden methods are being invoked?

**What's missing?**

```
let child = ViewControllerChild()
self.addChild(child)

/// Add this line
child.didMove(toParent: self)

self.view.addSubview(child.view)
```

Docs : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmovetoparentviewcontroller

> If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the didMove(toParent:) method of the child view controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or, if there is no transition, immediately after calling the addChild(_:) method.

Answer (score -1):

You need to trigger a size change event or actually change the view's size, so that the `viewWillTransition` method could be called.
In your code, the method will never be called because there is no view's size change action.
`viewWillTransition` method notifies the container that the size of its view is about to change.

Please refer this [code](https://github.com/jianghongbing/APIReferenceDemo/blob/6a2c507a0a17acdb8241cc052a156be3042e22d1/UIKit/UIContentContainer/UIContentContainer/ContainerViewController.swift) for your best practice.

**EDIT** regarding the sizeForChildContentContainer method, here is [the detailed use case](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/customizing-the-interface/embedding-the-pdfviewcontroller-inside-a-custom-container-view-controller/) you can go through with and will help you understand the usage.

Comment: size wont change. still no reason is visible. that was my fault i didnt mention about viewWillTransition invocation in question. did you see any clear consequences ofter overrding it but not using explicitly in code?